# MediaFrameReader not detecting webcam

Tags: uwp, webcam

I am using C# UWP MediaFrameReader/MediaCapture class to get access to my webcam, which is a small Logitech webcam. I follow all the examples from the following website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-media-frames-with-mediaframereader#create-a-frame-reader-for-the-frame-source\, an example from Microsoft.

Code is almost identical to the website's, and this is my structure:

```
public async void StartCameraPreview() {
    // Initialization code from the website goes here...
}

public void onFrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender,  MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Arrived");
}
```

For now I just want to test if `onFrameArrived()` is being called. But I notice that `MediaFrameSourceGroup selectedGroup` is null whenever I run the program, which tells me that the webcam/camera functionality is not being detected.

Did anyone have this issue? Any advice would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `sourceInfo.MediaStreamType == MediaStreamType.VideoRecord && sourceInfo.SourceKind == MediaFrameSourceKind.Color;` as my sourceInfo condition, and now it does detect. Although frames are still not being picked up! Nonetheless, first problem fixed.